# Wordpress Twenty Fifteen child theme blockquote

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am making a child theme for Twenty Fifteen from scratch. I am having problems with customizing the appearance of the the blockquote with CSS.

I have made some custom css for the blockquotes in the child theme:

```
border-left: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-left: 4px solid rgba(31, 31, 31, 1);
    border-style: inset;
    color: #0099cc;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.6667;
    margin-bottom: 1.6667em;
    padding-left: 0.7778em;
    padding-top: 0.7778em;
    padding-bottom: 0.7778em;
    padding-right: 0.7778em;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border-color: #cc0099;
```

This displays fine. The problem is that on smaller screens (notably mobile resolution) the blockquote css does not apply i.e the css of the "mother theme" is displayed instead. I can't seem to find out why.

Comment: Can you post the full CSS code? The codes that are affecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your parent theme they use several media queries to change what look like in the different screen devices size. Twenty Fifteen theme have several media queries:

```
    /**
     * 16.1 Mobile Large 620px
     */

    @media screen and (min-width: 38.75em) {


    }

    /**
     * 16.2 Tablet Small 740px
     */

    @media screen and (min-width: 46.25em) {


    }

    /**
     * 16.3 Tablet Large 880px
     */

    @media screen and (min-width: 55em) {


    }

and so on.....
```

On your child theme override it with value you want..

```
@media screen and (min-width: 38.75em) {

    blockquote {

      --- my value here ---

    }

}

other media screen queries..
```

---------------- update -----------------

try add this to your child theme

```
@media screen and (min-width: 55em) {
    blockquote {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-style: inset;
    color: #0099cc;
    border-left: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-left: 4px solid rgba(31, 31, 31, 1);
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border-color: #cc0099;
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 46.25em) {
blockquote {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border-style: inset;
    color: #0099cc;
    border-left: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-left: 4px solid rgba(31, 31, 31, 1);
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border-color: #cc0099;
    }
}

blockquote {
    padding-right: 0.7778em;
    border-style: inset;
    color: #0099cc;
    border-left: 4px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-left: 4px solid rgba(31, 31, 31, 1);
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    border-color: #cc0099;
}
```

@media screen and (min-width: 18.75em) no needed you can delete.

Comment: This helps a little. It works in some screen resolutions but it just does not work in the smallest screen resolutions i.e nothing below 620px width.

Comment: use @media only screen and (min-width: 18.75em) for 300px

Comment: Still does not work if I change it to 18.75em. I suspect that the main theme css has a different attribute than "@media screen and" but I really cannot find it. Oh dear.. This is getting frustrating.

Comment: The last of your answers worked for me, but only when I started from scratch with a new child style.css. In other words, I must have had something in the style.css that caused to override. Thanks